# issue adding sign in with apple to an iOS project that uses objc and swift code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to implement **sign in with apple** using their **AuthenticationServices framework** into my app which has both objc and swift code.

I have followed various tutorials to make sure I have included everything needed. I want to have this feature written in swift but when I am trying to build the app on the xcode simulator I am getting a few errors when the **project-Swift.h** file is being generated. Xcode complains that it cannot find
**protocol declarations for:
ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding   and
ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate**

[Example of errors in project-Swift.h is here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpC7o.png)

Looking around I have found several people who had issues with protocol declarations not being found in their **project-Swift.h** file but the solution was to import in a reference to the framework involved within their **Project-Bridging-Header.h** file. I did that as well in my **Project-Bridging-Header.h file** with this entry:

**#import <AuthenticationServices/AuthenticationServices.h>**

This unfortunately did not work. Does anyone have any insights or ideas that could help me out? I would like to implement this feature with swift code and not have to write it in objc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

solution was pretty simple.

I needed to add the following import to the **objc files** that had references to my **project-Swift.h** file. This caused **all the errors to resolve**. The following import needed to **go before** the import for **project-Swift.h**.

**#import <AuthenticationServices/AuthenticationServices.h>**